# Error parsing notification acknowledgment - Google checkout

Tags: notifications, google-checkout

Currently i have integrated Google checkout with my website in sandbox Environment.
When i am checking in integration console in my account, it shows following error

"We encountered an error processing your notification acknowledgment. The error we got is: Error parsing notification acknowledgment."

How to send acknowledge back to Google checkout?

Can anybody knows about this?

Answer (score 0):

The error in the Integration Console sugges that your server is not correctly acknowledging the notification:

http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_XML_API_Notification_API.html#responding_to_notifications

Some things to try:

1. Verify that you are correctly parsing the notification and correctly sending back the acknowledgement.
2. Verify that the XML response is correctly formated. Unlike HTML, XML parsers are picky about whitespaces, lower vs upper-case, proper syntax in general.

Also look at the notifications troubleshooting suggestions here:

http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/articles/Troubleshoot_Integration_Console_Errors.html

Comment: Now i have added  the following code in my callback web.config file to enable authentication
    <httpModules>
      <add name="BasicAuthenticationModule" type="GCheckout.Util.BasicAuthenticationModule,GCheckout"/>
    </httpModules>

Now i get the following error in integration console,
401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.
How to enable authentication?

Regards,
kannan.